# How to keep invisible button on recycleview if exit activity the open show visible

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

I am a problem on recycleview button if button click to show hide but exit app then open recycle view show button visible.

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            postattandance();
                            save.setEnabled(false);


                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
```

Comment: Couldn't understand your question, please clear it

Comment: You're a problem...? Guy, I think there's something wrong with your question

Comment: Question is not clear. Elaborate it.

Comment: sorry for weak english .my problem is i have a recycleview button if i click button to insert recycleview record on database  click button is hide but i exit app or back to other activity  then re open recycle view  to show again hide button not hide

Answer (score 0):

You need a database or something else (shared preference?) to store the value (show or hide). When restarting app it will go back to default. Instead, you should store the state of button in database, and when laucnhing activity request the DB to display